# Any need of viewstate in Ajax world

Tags: ajax, client-server, viewstate, updating

I want to create pages that has to be fully ajax enabled and I don't feel any need for viewstate and its very confusing to update viewstate when working with ajax. I don't want to use update panels. I want to manually update my aspx page using ajax and doing this is leaving me stunned. In this case should I use asp.net controls. The whole model of asp.net seems clumsy. Sever and Client are trying to impose different standards on poor html page. please help this has become a nightmare for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using asp.net controls and since you mentioned viewstate, I take it you are building a webforms app. 
   .net controls require viewstate, scriptmanager and all the bell & whistles.

If however you want to keep everything lightweight, I'd suggest using asmx services and call those from client. That way you will not need to use any viewstate, .net controls or a scriptmanager.

Comment: If I want to implement a model similar to facebook then what is the recommended way to do it? I think asp.net do not support multiple updates at a time too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by multiple updates. Facebook = multiple web services called from javascript.

Comment: Don't you know Asp.net ajax don't allow multiple updates at a time? You can activate one update panel at a time. if you try another one the first one will be cancelled if the first is already in progress.